# DisableRequestSizeLimit and RequestFormLimits not work on server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core API for uploading file as below. Initially it failed on large file. After set the [DisableRequestSizeLimit] and [RequestFormLimits], the API can work for larger file. But when I deploy it to server, large file will fail while it works fine on my development machine. Would anyone advise if any additional setting is required?

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public ActionResult UploadDoc([FromForm] IFormFile content)
```

Comment: Hi @Sang, which is your server?

Comment: Hi @Rena, it is Windows Server 2019

Comment: I figured out the issue is due to URL Rewrite is used in IIS to redirect "http://<server>/api/xxx" to "http://<server:10000>/api/xxx", and the limit is now in IIS. 

Would anyone advise how to adjust the setting for this case that the .NET Core API is hosting under Kestrel but using IIS for redirection?